# Bundler could not find compatible versions for multiple gems that seem to fall within range of requirements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, compatibility

I'm trying to use a gem `spree`, which depends on `kaminari (~> 1.0.1)`. In my `Gemfile.lock`, I have `kaminari (= 1.1.1)`. This satisfies the requirement for `spree`, since it's greater than or equal to the last digit. However, I'm getting this error when I try to bundle:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "kaminari":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    kaminari (= 1.1.1)

  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin (~> 1.3) was resolved to 1.3.0, which depends on
      kaminari (>= 0.15)

    rails_admin (~> 1.3) was resolved to 1.3.0, which depends on
      kaminari (< 2.0, >= 0.14)

    spree (~> 3.5.0) was resolved to 3.5.0, which depends on
      spree_core (= 3.5.0) was resolved to 3.5.0, which depends on
        kaminari (~> 1.0.1)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

I'm not sure why v1.1.1 doesn't satisfy the requirements for all the gems in question, since it seems to fall within the range for all gems in question. I tried running `bundle update`, but then I get a long list of gem incompatibilities, none of which make sense to me either, since their requirements all seem to fall within range of the version I have in my lock file. For instance,

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    carrierwave (~> 1.2) was resolved to 1.2.2, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 4.0.0)

    rails (~> 5.1.6) was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
      activemodel (= 5.1.6)

    web-console (>= 3.3.0) was resolved to 3.6.2, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 5.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    annotate (~> 2.7) was resolved to 2.7.4, which depends on
      activerecord (< 6.0, >= 3.2)

    friendly_id (~> 5.2) was resolved to 5.2.4, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)

    rails (~> 5.1.6) was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
      activerecord (= 5.1.6)

    activeadmin (~> 1.3) was resolved to 1.3.0, which depends on
      ransack (~> 1.3) was resolved to 1.8.8, which depends on
        activerecord (>= 3.0)

    spree_gateway (~> 3.3) was resolved to 3.3.3, which depends on
      spree_extension was resolved to 0.0.5, which depends on
        activerecord (>= 4.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin (~> 1.3) was resolved to 1.3.0, which depends on
      arbre (>= 1.1.1) was resolved to 1.1.1, which depends on
        activesupport (>= 3.0.0)

    carrierwave (~> 1.2) was resolved to 1.2.2, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)

    activeadmin (~> 1.3) was resolved to 1.3.0, which depends on
      inherited_resources (>= 1.7.0) was resolved to 1.8.0, which depends on
        has_scope (~> 0.6) was resolved to 0.7.2, which depends on
          activesupport (>= 4.1)

    jbuilder (~> 2.5) was resolved to 2.7.0, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)

    kaminari (~> 1.0.1) was resolved to 1.0.1, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)

    rails (~> 5.1.6) was resolved to 5.1.6, which depends on
      activesupport (= 5.1.6)

    activeadmin (~> 1.3) was resolved to 1.3.0, which depends on
      ransack (~> 1.3) was resolved to 1.8.8, which depends on
        activesupport (>= 3.0)

    spring was resolved to 2.0.2, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.2)

    sass-rails (~> 5.0) was resolved to 5.0.7, which depends on
      sprockets-rails (< 4.0, >= 2.0) was resolved to 3.2.1, which depends on
        activesupport (>= 4.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "kaminari":
  In Gemfile:
    kaminari (~> 1.0.1)

    activeadmin (~> 1.3) was resolved to 1.3.0, which depends on
      kaminari (>= 0.15)

    rails_admin (~> 1.3) was resolved to 1.3.0, which depends on
      kaminari (< 2.0, >= 0.14)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spree_core":
  In Gemfile:
    spree (~> 3.5.0) was resolved to 3.5.0, which depends on
      spree_core (= 3.5.0)

    spree_gateway (~> 3.3) was resolved to 3.3.3, which depends on
      spree_core (< 4.0, >= 3.1.0)
```

These errors raise a whole new set of questions, since I don't see any conflicts in versions for any of the gems.

For `activemodel`, why can't it use 5.1.6? Doesn't that satisfy all the requirements?

For `activerecord`, why can't it use 5.1.6? Doesn't that satisfy all the requirements?

For `activesupport`, why can't it use 5.1.6? Doesn't that satisfy all the requirements?

For `kaminari`, why can't it use 1.0.1? Doesn't that satisfy all the requirements?

For `spree_core`, why can't it use 3.5.0? Doesn't that satisfy all the requirements?

How does one go about resolving these issues? I've tried running `bundle update` for all gems and for individual gems, but I get the same error message either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This satisfies the requirement for spree, since it's greater than or equal to the last digit.

That's not quite correct, the [docs for Bundler's Gemfile](https://bundler.io/v1.16/gemfile.html#gemfiles) state:

> The specifier `~>` has a special meaning, best shown by example. `~> 2.0.3` is identical to `>= 2.0.3` and `< 2.1`.

So in your case, for kaminari, `~> 1.0.1` would mean `'>= 1.0.1'` and `'< 1.1'`, which (obviously) `1.1.1` does not meet.

As for the others, everything *looks* to me like it'd work, though I notice a lot of the ones failing need something to do with spree or kaminari, so maybe fixing the one will help those. The others could also (maybe) be cascading errors, kind of like a missing parenthesis or comma in one place can cause syntax errors through the entire file, maybe just the one error is cascading through the rest of the bundle, I'd take care of Kaminari and then see what you're left with.

Comment: I must have missed that. Well I've tried specifying `gem 'kaminari', '~> 1.0.1'` at the top of my Gemfile, but running `bundle install` gives me 

`You have requested:
  kaminari ~> 1.0.1

The bundle currently has kaminari locked at 1.1.1.
Try running 'bundle update kaminari'

If you are updating multiple gems in your Gemfile at once,
try passing them all to 'bundle update'`. 
After I run `bundle update kaminari`, it gives me the same long list of incompatibilities. I've tried deleting my .lock file, and I've tried `gem install kaminari -v '~> 1.0.1'`

Comment: @Doug Just out of curiosity, what happens if you temporarily comment out **rails_admin** from your gem file? I've recreated a Gemfile as best I could from your error messages and everything works perfect until I try adding in that gem, then all hell breaks loose for me

Comment: Strange, commenting out `rails_admin` fixed the problem... But it says it requires `kaminari (< 2.0, >= 0.14)`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified whether the version of spree you're trying to install is compatible with the higher version of kaminari? try downgrading the kaminari gem to "~> 1.0.1" to see if that helps.

if that does not work, then another suggestion would be to run "bundle update" on your current gemset "before" you add "spree" to your Gemfile to make sure you are working with all the latest versions of your currently installed gems.